# Remove records from a dictionary of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to delete records from a dictionary of list:

```
data{'key1':[value1,value2,value3,value4]
     'key2':[value1,value2,value3,value4]
     'key3':[value1,value2,value3,value4]}
```

how to delete all value2 in all keys?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {
           'key1':['value1','value2','value3','value4'],
           'key2':['value1','value2','value3','value4'],
           'key3':['value1','value2','value3','value4']
        }

for v in data.values():
  if 'value2' in v:
    v.remove('value2')
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to delete records from a list for given dict.

```
data = {
       'key1':['value1','value2','value3','value4'],
       'key2':['value1','value2','value3','value4'],
       'key3':['value1','value2','value3','value4']
    }
```

Using ***remove*** method:

```
for keys, values in data.items():
    if 'value2' in values:
        data[keys].remove('value2')
```

Using ***pop*** method:

```
for keys, values in data.items():
    if 'value2' in values:
        values.pop(values.index('value2'))
```

Using ***del*** keyword:

```
for keys, values in data.items():
    if 'value2' in values:
        del values[values.index('value2')]
```